# background-color just working for 1st cell

Tags: html, css

```
...
    <th style='background-color:#cccccc;font-weight:bold'><td></td><td>Anschrift</td><td>Nachname</td><td>Vorname</td><td>PLZ</td><td>Ort</td></th>
    ...
```

I wonder why just the first cell of the th is being formatted by the style attributes, any ideas about this? Any help appreciated, regards Ismir

edit: 1st empty cell is intended

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<th>` is `<td>` for header cells, it's not container for `<td>` instead of `<tr>`. Just replace `<th>` with `<tr>` (styling row) and eventually replace `<td>` with `<th>`.

Comment: `td`s should be wrapped with a `tr` - `th` is a heading and like a `td` but bold.  the clue is in the tag name: `tr`: table row, `th`: table header, `td`: table data (or cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the remainder of your HTML, I'd start by reformatting your code as follows:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>TABLE HEADING</th>
    <th>TABLE HEADING</th>
    <th>TABLE HEADING</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anschrift</td>
    <td>Nachname</td>
    <td>Vorname</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That may well be one of the issues you're encountering, you were wrapping `<tr>`'s, `<td>`'s in a table heading element.

Comment: oh, ok, that helped, thk u a lot

Comment: No problem, glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap `<th>` in `<tr>`, not `<td>` in `<th>`.

Also, it is considered bad practice to use inline styles. I would highly suggest using CSS separate from the HTML.

```
<tr style="background-color: #ccc; font-weight: bold">
  <th></th>
  <th>Anschrift</th>
  <th>Nachname</th>
  <th>Vorname</th>
  <th>PLZ</th>
  <th>Ort</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ok. Now my th's are bold formatted, but the background is still just formatted for the 1st cell

Comment: If needed here is a link to an example: http://codepen.io/bartuc/pen/wMdvrY
The background color should span the entire header.